# XML Schema - Restrict the appearance of elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I have multiple XML descriptor files in my actual project and I'm having troubles with creating corresponding XSDs.

I have my custom types in XML, for example:

```
<A>
  <B>
    ...
  </B>
</A>
```

I need to create template blocks in my XML file. These blocks may contain any elements of my custom types. However, there is a slight difference between an element in the templates and elements elsewhere: they may have a `Parameter` element

```
<Template>
  <Parameter />
  <A>
    <Parameter />
    <B>
      <Parameter />
      ...
    </B>
  </A>
</Template>
```

As far as I know, it is impossible for to declare that the `<Parameter>` element can appear anywhere inside `<Template>` (including the child nodes). But I can do this by defining `<Parameter>` as an element of all of my type definitions.

However I want to restrict the `<Parameter>` so that it can only appear when its parent is inside a `<Template>` element. Is it possible to put the `<Parameter>` in a type definition but restrict its appearance to when its parent is in the scope of a `<Template>` tag?

How can I write this in XSD?

Comment: *As far as I know, it is impossible to let <Parameter> element appear anywhere inside <Template>.*  What does this mean?

Comment: If I well understand XML Schema, I cannot declare an element (Parameter for now), which may appear anywhere inside another (among its descendants) (Template for now). I have to refer Parameter as child of all the others instead (don't I?). (Template, A, and B all may have this element inside). But I don't want to let A or B have any `<Parameter>` children if they are not in a Template.

Comment: That's correct - you would have to add it to each element `A`, `B`, etc. But you should be able to restrict the `Parameter` element from being valid if the `A` element is not inside a `Template`. Ok, now I see what your question is.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. Thanks for making my question clearer. I hope, someone may help me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation I don't believe this is possible.  There are a number of relevant questions on SO that relate to this, and the general advice is that elements of an XSD can't be dependent on other elements of an XSD.

Instead, you may need to consider some alternative approaches or workarounds.

Without knowing your requirement it's difficult to consider what else might work for you, but perhaps you could tie the `Template` and `Parameter` more closely together, and less closely with the other elements. Foe example, a `Template` might have a `Parameter`, another `Template`, and an element (the `A`, `B`, etc):

Define a `Template` like this:

```
<Template>
    <xsd:Sequence>
        <Parameter />
        <xsd:ComplexType />
        <Template />
    </xsd:Sequence>
</Template>
```

And then each element does not need to be modified, but instead the `Template` type stores the structure.

```
<Template>
    <Parameter />
    <A>
    <Template>
        <Parameter />
        <B>
        <Template>
            <Parameter />
            < .. anything else .. />
        </Template>
    </Template>
</Template>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have already figured out some alternative solutions too (which are - of course - less convenient and less elegant than the desired one with that restriction). I accepted your answer anyway.